# What exactly was Glen Talbot's rank in S.H.I.E.L.D. as of the end of Season 4?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, agents-of-shield

In Season 4 Episode 22 of *Agents of S.H.I.E.L.D.*, Glen Talbot gives Phil Coulson some orders on appearing at a meeting regarding S.H.I.E.L.D.. In addition, he also acts as if on behalf of S.H.I.E.L.D. during the series, especially that season. My question is, what exactly is Talbot's rank/position within S.H.I.E.L.D.? Or, if it changes over time, what is it during each season or each time it changes?

Comment: IIRC, Talbot wasn't actually part of SHIELD but part of the US government that frequently works alongside SHIELD, or has similar interests.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Talbot was in more of an oversight role rather than a direct member of the original SHIELD.

As the person eventually in charge of the ATCU he became the "face" of the "new SHIELD" for the public.

[From the wiki](https://marvelcinematicuniverse.fandom.com/wiki/Glenn_Talbot)

> Brigadier General Glenn Talbot was a high-ranking officer for the United States Air Force. Following all the terrorist attacks connected to the HYDRA Uprising, Talbot was tasked with capturing the remaining S.H.I.E.L.D. facilities, for which he was promoted. Despite their long standing feud and constant attempts to out do one another, Talbot had grown to respect S.H.I.E.L.D. new Director, Phil Coulson, accepting his help in the War on HYDRA. All his experiences in dealing with S.H.I.E.L.D. had resulted with President Matthew Ellis putting Talbot in charge of the ATCU, which was re-purposed to serve as the public face of S.H.I.E.L.D. after Rosalind Price's death, as Talbot used his position to assist S.H.I.E.L.D. with their wars against Gideon Malick and Hive, while also successfully destroying HYDRA for good and ending their long conflict.
>
> With the return of S.H.I.E.L.D., Talbot was tasked with finding their new Director, and developed Project Patriot to find a new Captain America with Jeffrey Mace.

Answer (score 0):

He was in charge of appointing a Director of S.H.I.E.L.D., and is the liaison between S.H.I.E.L.D. and the U.S. Government. That puts him in an equivalent role to [Alexander Pierce](https://marvelcinematicuniverse.fandom.com/wiki/Alexander_Pierce), who was the Secretary of the World Security Council.

Whether the World Security Council still exists in unclear. [Gideon Malick](https://marvelcinematicuniverse.fandom.com/wiki/Gideon_Malick) was also a member, but had left at some point and orchestrated the founding of the ATCU. Perhaps the council was re-formed free of HYDRA influence, or perhaps S.H.I.E.L.D. no longer has any direct international oversight, and is now under the sole jurisdiction of the U.S. Government (though still subject to Sokovia Accords).

Given the end of the TV series and its increasingly disputed canonicity, we are unlikely to find out.